# Get values between DIV tags?

Tags: javascript

How do I get the values in between a DIV tag?

**Example**

```
<div id="myOutput" class="wmd-output">
    <pre><code><p>hello world!</p></code></pre>
</div>
```

my output values I should get is

```
<pre><code><p>hello world!</p></pre>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, find the element.  The fastest way is by ID.  Next, use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:element.innerHTML) to get the HTML content of the element.

```
document.getElementById('myOutput').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 4):

innerHtml is good for this case as guys suggested before me,

If you have more complex html structure and want to traverse/manipulate it I suggest to use js libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com). To get want you want it would be:

```
$('#myOutput').html()
```

Looks nicer I think (but I wouldn't load whole js library just for such simple example of course)

Answer (score 1):

Just putting all above with some additional details,

If you are not sure about that div having some id is not there on html page then to make it sure please use.

```
var objDiv = document.getElementbyId('myOutput');
if(objDiv){
  objDiv.innerHTML;
}
```

This will avoid any JavaScript error on the page.